# Windows software to delete files matching criteria when drive space is low?

Tags: windows, file-management

I would like to find some software that runs in the background that detects when a specific drive's free space goes below a certain threshold and then cleans out any files matching a specific criteria (mainly age)

Would anyone know any free tools that would do this?

Comment: It is not particularly difficult to write a script to do this using AutoIt.  Is such a tool acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

It does not exactly fall under your specifications because as far as I know it cannot delete files based on age but [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/index.html) will show you your drives and where the space is being taken up, along with file types. It has an advanced feature called cleanups where you can specify commands to automatically clear files.

[image: WinDirStat]

Comment: Please edit your original question and add this as a second option.

Comment: I did not ask a question I provided multiple answers, as per [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-to-do-when-an-answer-contains-several-suggestions) and [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). Keeping multiple answers separate so votes can be cast for individual recommendations. Having two recommendations in one answer in my opinion, makes little to no sense and goes against how the voting system works.

Comment: yeah I love these kinds of programs, I use [RidNacs: Disk Space Usage Analyzer | Freeware - SplashSoft.de](http://www.splashsoft.de/Freeware/ridnacs-disk-space-usage-analyzer.html) for that, it's great. However, the scenario I'm talking about is something completely different (I have a ramdisk - so small, only 100mb, where I output a ton of temporary HTML files from the program I'm developing.These add up quickly, so it would be nice to delete them to free space on a constant basis, while leaving the most recent files intact so I can still reference them)

Comment: Ah, in that case I don't know of a software that does specifically that, however like the comment on your question says, your best bet may be to write a script that runs in the background and deletes files from X directory if the file is older than X days or similar.

Answer (score 1):

[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can automatically scan your computer and remove old cached system files, log files, browser files and several other programs and file caches. It can also preform registry cleanup, manage startup programs and many other tools.

[image: CCleaner]

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Where can I set a disk limit so that it runs?

Comment: @ThomasWeller In the Options -> Monitoring, you can enable System monitoring. Some of the advanced features are locked in the free version but they will let you select an amount of space and to prompt for a cleaning or to automatically clean.

Comment: FYI: Microsoft officially says not to use CCleaner as it can sometimes cause problems in the registry. Sorry I don't have a link to that statement right now.

Comment: I always preform a registry backup before using the registry cleaner. If you manage to find the article I would be interested in reading it.

Answer (score 0):

- Open a cmd window go to the root dir, and use `del *.bak /s`. It deletes files matching that filespec in all subdirs.
- The same works for `*.~`, `tmp*`, `tmp*.*`, etc.